# Making QPushButton background constant

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I use C++/Qt 5.12, Windows 7 OS, Visual Studio 2017.

I'd like checkable `QPushButton` background to ignore checked/pressed state. I'd like to have a default background in a `QPushButton` instance, but only font color should be changed if the user checked the button. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QSS (CSS with Qt's flavor) to customize QWidgets:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

I would recommend creating an application-wide QSS that you load at startup, and use `QApplication::setStyleSheet(...)`. But you can use Qt Designer (right click on a specific control), or plain C++

```
myButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: yellow; }");
```

You may need to redefine `border` to have it visually applied, and then `margins` to have a correct button size, but it is fairly easy. Try experimenting from Qt Designer.

You can find a comprehensive reference of all selectors and attributes available here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html